# С++ Возникла Ошибка error C4716: operator<<: должна возвращать значение

Tags: visual-c++

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const PT &p) {
    os << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << ")";

}
```

как исправить код?

Comment: `return os;` написать

Answer (score 1):

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const PT& p)
{
    os << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << ")";
    return os;
}
```